# Gcm devices registration ERROR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to build a gcm app that will receive push notification from server.but when I execute the code on emulator or real device this is what I get on LogCat

```
I/===GCMIntentService===(6977): Device registered: regId = reg number here
V/GCMBaseIntentService(6977): Releasing wakelock
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6977): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6977): GCM IntentService class: com.my.app.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService(6977): Acquiring wakelock
V/GCMBaseIntentService(6977): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-303034343665-2
D/GCMBaseIntentService(6977): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = null, unregistered = com.my.app
D/GCMRegistrar(6977): resetting backoff for com.my.app
V/GCMRegistrar(6977): Saving regId on app version 2
D/dalvikvm(6977): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 247K, 12% free 3168K/3580K, paused 29ms, total 34ms
I/===GCMIntentService===(6977): unregistered = reg number here
V/GCMBaseIntentService(6977): Releasing wakelock
```

Anyone can help me with this please!

```
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.my.app" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: upload ur manifest file

Comment: Does the phone has a google account registered in it?

Comment: @ Droidee yess both have emulator + device

Comment: view my Manifest file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12071927/2106338 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/12052487/2106338 please refer the answers in the links.

Comment: chech this part in your code:                                             GCMRegistrar.checkDevice( this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest( this);
if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered( this))
{
Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId( this));
}
   final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId( this);
System.out.println(regId);
r=regId;
if (regId.equals("")) {
GCMRegistrar.register( this, "<----UR ID---->");
Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId( this));
    r=regId;
    System.out.println(r);
   } else {
    Log.d("info", "already registered as" + regId);
   }

Comment: notification is second thing first i need my device to get registered!!dont u think?? because right now i am having issue with registering my devic.

Comment: @appubala yes i did checked with this code but still same error

Comment: you check in real device/emulator?did you receive id?

Comment: ya i do receive a id on both but then unregistered